# Creality Ender-3 V2 motors going insane

Tags: creality-ender-3, extruder, firmware, motor, bug

I recently started using my Ender 3 V2 again because I needed it to print a hook. I went through multiple problems that I could solve by updating the firmware but after starting the print, I heard a very hard noise that made me understand that the stepper motors were going over their limit and, after trying a second time, I saw that every axis was going to +infinite position.

I didn't try much things as I am not comfortable with this but I think it comes from the firmware.

If you have the solution please help me because I can't print anything and I think it damages the printer.

Comment: What firmware did you flash? Where did you get it from?

Comment: I used the 1.0.4 firmware from the creality website. I made sure to check if it was the one that has no bltouch as i don't have one

Comment: I assume you are talking about [this site](https://www.creality.com/pages/download-ender-3-v2?spm=..page_1934481.products_display_1.1). Try flashing firmware from third position - **Ender-3 V2_Marlin2.0.8_HW_V4.2.2_SW_V1.0.7 (11 Aug. 2022)**. This seems to be the most appropriate firmware for you at this moment. You should find there new firmware file: `Ender-3 V2_HW_V4.2.2_SW_V1.0.7_202200811.bin`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your axes are inverted.

First be sure to get the right configuration file for your marlin version, printer, and control board from the [Marlin Github Config page](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations)
your board shall be CrealityV422 if it is a stock one.

If it is still a problem you can of course invert the axes in the config file:

```
#define INVERT_X_DIR true //or false
#define INVERT_Y_DIR true //or false
#define INVERT_Z_DIR true //or false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect the firmware isolate it by trying a different build.

Try the MRisCoc professional firmware. It is a fork of Marlin 2 with many extra features. If your machine is unmodified - no BLTouch etc - the current version is

https://github.com/mriscoc/Ender3V2S1/releases/download/20230522/Ender3V2-422-MM-MPC-20230522B.bin

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Your answer reads as an advertisement for the firmware, but it does not address the question. Please state your affiliation and modify the answer to answer the question to prevent down-voting your question. Since you are new, please read our [help] and take the [tour].

Comment: This firmware does indeed look very interesting. Thank you for the suggestion.